# SSPI problem on VB.net connection whith mysql

Tags: vb.net, winforms

I can't connect to my database when i click on my button and I always come across a message like this even when changing my code

```
</StackTrace><ExceptionString>System.ComponentModel.Win32Exception (0x80004005): Le message reçu était inattendu ou formaté de façon incorrecte</ExceptionString><NativeErrorCode>80090326</NativeErrorCode></InnerException></Exception></TraceRecord>
Une exception non gérée du type 'System.Security.Authentication.AuthenticationException' s'est produite dans MySql.Data.dll
Échec d'un appel à SSPI, consultez l'exception interne.
```

```
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Public Class Form1
    Dim conn As New MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlConnection
    Dim myConnectionString As String
    Private Sub connection_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles connection.Click
        myConnectionString = "server=localhost;database=sakila;uid=root;pwd=;Integrated Security=SSPI"
        Try
            conn.ConnectionString = myConnectionString
            conn.Open()

        Catch ex As MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlException
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub
End Class
```

I don't understand where is the problem.
please help me.

Comment: SSPI is for SQL Server, not MySQL. See [here](https://www.connectionstrings.com/mysql/) for information relating to MySQL connection strings.

Comment: What @jmcilhinney said. I just want to note that providing a username and (empty) password is pointless when using Integrated Security, as that instructs the SQL client to authenticate with Windows Authentication, i.,e. the current Windows user account.